# convert nested for loop into a nested while loop JAVA

Tags: java, for-loop, while-loop

I'm a beginner and I need to convert this "for" loop into a "while" loop.

```
int s = 0;
int t = 1;

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    s = s + i;
    for (int j = i; j > 0; j--) {
        t = t + (j - 1);
    }
    s = s + t;
    System.out.println("T is " + t);
}
System.out.println("S is " + s);
```

I tried this and it didn't work

```
int s = 0;
int t = 1;
int i = 0;

while (i < 5)
    i++;
{
    s = s + i;
    int j = i;

    while (j > 0)
        j--;
    {
        t = t + (j - 1);
    }
    s = s + t;
    System.out.println("T is " + t);
}
System.out.println("S is " + s);
```

the output was T=0 and S = 5
when it should read

```
T is 1
T is 1
T is 2
T is 5
T is 11
S is 30
```

thanks

Comment: `i++;` should be before the closing bracket `}`, thus inside the block, not before the opening bracket. `while(...) {...; i++; }`

Answer (score 0):

```
int s = 0;
int t = 1;
int i = 0;

while (i < 5) 
{
    s = s + i;
    int j = i;

    while (j > 0) 
    {
        t = t + (j-1);
        j--;
    }
    i++;
    s = s + t;
    System.out.println("T is " + t);
}
System.out.println("S is " + s);
```

You should look into the syntax more carefully. Otherwise you were executing the blocks single time.

Earlier you were running this

```
while (i < 5) 
    i++;
```

Which is basically executing the loop 5 times and after the end of the loop `i` gets the value of 5.

After that we are running the block and we encounter the while loop again.

```
while (j > 0) 
        j--;
```

It executes 5 times again. So it would be `j=0` after this loop ends.

So you end up with `t=0` and `s=5`. That's it.

Comment: @TJW.: If it helped select the answer

Answer (score 0):

The `i++;` should be inside the loop's brackets, not placed before. Same with `j`.

```
while (i < 5) 
{
    s = s + i;
    int j = i;

    while (j > 0) 
    {
        t = t + (j-1);
        j--; // j needs to be incremented here
    }
    s = s + t;
    i++; // i needs to be incremented here
}
```

As it currently is, you have a loop where the only statement is `i++;`, and then the rest of the code, which is in its own code block (or local scope), is executed only once.